# SSIS DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR

Tags: ssis, derived-column

I am getting the following error message for my SSIS package:

*Error: 0xC0049063 at Data Flow Task, Calculate Percentage Change [34]: The conditional operation failed.
Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Calculate Percentage Change [34]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.*

The expression inside Calculate Percentage Change works for some of the data, I thought it could be a length issue so I put a 1000 for the text data but it still not working:

*Base_P100PremiumAmount_Curr != Base_P100PremiumAmount_Prev ? ((DT_WSTR,1000)ABS((Base_P100PremiumAmount_Prev / (Base_P100PremiumAmount_Curr) * 100 - 100)) + "%") : (RetentionAmount_Curr != RetentionAmount_Prev ? (DT_WSTR,1000)ABS((RetentionAmount_Prev / (RetentionAmount_Curr) * 100 - 100)) + "%" : (SignedSharePct_Curr != SignedSharePct_Prev ? (DT_WSTR,1000)ABS((SignedSharePct_Prev / (SignedSharePct_Curr) * 100 - 100)) + "%" : ""))*

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the issue was  dividing by zero.